# Return values from Obj if key in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm still learning basics of map(), filter(), forEach(), and includes() and can't seem to figure out the best way or anyway of attempting this...

Let's say I've got an arr and an obj and I need to return the object values if object key is in the array

const array = [1, 2, 3];

const object = { 1: "blue", 2: "red", 3: "green", 4: "orange", 5: "purple" };

I believe because I'm going for a new array, I need to use map()

Comment: what is the expected output for the given input?

Comment: attempting to return object.values-- so in this case, return blue, red, green

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.entries(object) to get an array of key value pairs of the object, then filter according to the array elements, finally map and return only the values:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

const object = { 1: "blue", 2: "red", 3: "green", 4: "orange", 5: "purple" };

const result = Object.entries(object).filter(el=>array.includes(parseInt(el[0]))).map(el=>el[1])

console.log(result)
```

Or if you want to keep the order order of the elements (thanks to ASDFGerte), just map over the `array` and return the value of the element.

```js
const array = [3,2,1];
const object = { 1: "blue", 2: "red", 3: "green", 4: "orange", 5: "purple" };

const result = array.map(el => object[el]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yes true, it's best to understand if you log all outcomes of the methods separately console.log(Object.entries(object))
console.log(Object.entries(object).filter(el=>array.includes(parseInt(el[0]))))
console.log(Object.entries(object).filter(el=>array.includes(parseInt(el[0]))).map(el=>el[1]))

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution! ... could you possibly help an early learn &tell me how I'm to read this?

My attempt:

passing the obj as a parameter into the Object.entries converts the obj into an arr of arrays (E.G., [ ["1","blue"], ["2","red"], ["3","green"], ...etc]

then with the filter, we use it to make a callback

the callback is array.includes() which uses el as the argument that is currently being processed in the array-- in thise case because we turned the object in an array of arrays, we are starting at Int([0])

then we use map() to create a new array? what's[1]?

Comment: From Objects.entries you get an array of arrays containing the key and value pairs of the object. then we pass the array of arrays to the filter method, returning only the elements of the array which include as a key one of the elements of "array". Then we use map() to create a new array with the values of the object from the residing filtered entries.

Comment: thank you so much for telling me to console.log, I will attempt this and learn-- very much appreciate your time helping a rookie

Comment: Although the question is unclear about the details i'll mention, the behavior here looks unintentional. Order of the input array is not kept: `[2, 1, 3]` would yield the same output order `['blue', 'red', 'green']`. A nested `includes` means O(n²) when length and keys are similar. Also, strictly speaking, `parseInt` is an information-losing operation, consider e.g. `{ '1e0': 'blue' }`. From how the question is posed, i'd guess the desired answer is `array.map(e => object[e])`, potentially with a filter beforehand, but unlikely: `array.filter(e => Object.hasOwn(object, e)).map(e => object[e])`.

Answer (score 0):

We will only be returning values with keys that are present in the array. So you can simply iterate through the array values, and check if there is a value in the object with the array value as the key. Since you want it to return the values from the call itself maybe we can use reduce:

```
let values = array.reduce((found, item) => {
    return (item in object) ? found.push(object[item]) && found : found
}, [])
console.log(values)
```

Comment: Thanks @limekin for your response, I haven't yet learned .reduce() yet but will try and attempt to dissect your code tomorrow as well to push my learning-- very much appreciate your contribution!

Comment: `object[item] ?` is a dirty way to check, values might be falsy. Use `Object.hasOwn`, or if prototypes are included, the `in` operator. `concat` in a loop like this results in an O(n²) operation, you are potentially copying the array every time. This is unnecessary.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Good to know, updated. hasOwn seems to be experimental, so I went with in.

Comment: `Object.hasOwn` is an ES2022 addition to shorten `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`, see [the related (finished) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-accessible-object-hasownproperty).

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Good to know again. Thanks a lot for the link, will check.